# why does subtraction between dates return a Rational type?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to perform subtraction operation on dates.

```
date_sent = Date.parse("2013-01-01") #=> Tue, 01 Jan 2013
date_now = Date.today  #=> Wed, 04 Sep 2013
days = (date_now - date_sent) #=> (246/1)
```

Why does `date_now - date_sent` return a `Rational` type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the expected behavior. From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D):

> **d - other → date or rational**
>
> ```
> Date.new(2001,2,3) - 1               #=> #<Date: 2001-02-02 ...>
> Date.new(2001,2,3) - Date.new(2001)  #=> (33/1)
> ```

A rational type is used because it can express the difference exactly:

```
diff = DateTime.new(2001,2,3) - DateTime.new(2001,2,2,1)
#=> (23/24)
```

Whereas float can't:

```
diff.to_f
#=> 0.9583333333333334
```

Comment: how can I convert Rational to minutes?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp multiply by 1440 (1 day = 1440 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

[Because](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) you may want to find a difference between two `DateTime`s, which may be `Rational`. E.g.:

```
DateTime.new(2001,2,3) - DateTime.new(2001,2,2,12)
# ⇒ (1/2)
```

Comment: Whether the two times are **less than a day apart** does not matter. Even for two times that are years apart, you need this feature to know the difference with the **accuracy of less than a day**.

Comment: I just used an example from ruby-doc.

Comment: I am not mentioning your example. I am mentioning your explanation.

Comment: Now, your answer is a tautology. X because X.

Comment: @sawa Please go read the dictionary for the word “tautology” explanation. `DateTime` mentioned makes it not.

Answer (score 2):

This was confusing also for me.

The difference between days is always an integer, so why express it as a rational?

That's because it"s the same return type used to express the difference between a Date and a DateTime, or two DateTime. that way you can express a difference between two time.

I am personally not convinced it's the best choice, for instance:

```
Time.now.to_datetime-Date.today
```

returns:

```
=> (44150896597/86400000000)
```

It think this was clearer:

```
=> 0.5110978639814815
```

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes such comparison like below would happen:

```
date_sent = DateTime.parse("2013-01-01 12:00:00") # with half a day
date_now = Date.today

days = (date_now - date_sent) # => (491/2)
```