# Iterate over dates to find days between dates

Tags: ruby, date, methods

I have an array of dates and I need to have each date figure out the difference between the next date so for example

```
a= {1=>03-01-2015, 2=>03-10-2015, 3=>03-15-2015, 4=>03-27-2015}
```

A full object looks like this...

```
#<Transaction:0xc413c58 @id="KYYEZEPedacrwBkpqDk8C5Yy04BqvJIXJdYXJ", @account="Ppp575Ke19T8PxrAdMrNUq4Ox4AQVrHMLa5D0", @date="2013-10-23", @amount=100, @name="COMED", @meta={"is_risky"=>false, "location"=>{"store_number"=>"10782"}}, @location=nil, @pending=false, @score={"location"=>{}, "name"=>0.2}, @type={"primary"=>"unresolved"}, @category=nil, @category_id=nil>]
```

should return

```
{9,5,12} #the days between each 2 dates
```

here is what I have so far...

```
@collect_transactions = (@user.transactions.find_all { |t| t.name == 'due_at' })
@date_difference = @collect_transactions.map(&:date).each_cons(2) { |a,b| b-a }
```

I am not sure if each_cons is the right method but my response right now is this...

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "2015-01-15":String
```

It is not counting the days...Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are some ambiguities in the question. Firstly, you say you have an `Array` of dates, but show a `Hash`. Also, there are two different date formats mixed in the question. Please sort these out to help us give a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) is the way to go. You just have to first convert the date strings to date objects. You could do it as follows.

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def date_diffs(h)    
  h.values.
    map { |s| Date.strptime(s,'%m-%d-%Y') }.
    each_cons(2).
    map { |d1,d2| (d2-d1).to_i }
end
```

**Example**

```
h = { 1=>"03-01-2015", 2=>"03-10-2015", 3=>"03-15-2015", 4=>"03-27-2015" }

date_diffs(h)
  #=> [9, 5, 12]
```

**Discussion**

From the edit to your question, it appears you may need to use the date format string `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Another option is to use [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) rather than [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_strptime). (I generally prefer `strptime` because it is more demanding.)

You must of course ensure that the hash values are in the correct order. If you are using a version of Ruby prior to 1.9 (when there was no guarantee of the order of hash keys, or even a concept of key order), or you using a more recent version (where key insertion order is maintained), but are unsure about the order of the keys, you could do this as a first step:

```
values = h.values_at(*(1..4))
  #=> ["03-01-2015", "03-10-2015", "03-15-2015", "03-27-2015"]
```

**Explanation**

We have:

```
b = h.values
  #=> ["03-01-2015", "03-10-2015", "03-15-2015", "03-27-2015"] 
c = b.map { |s| Date.strptime(s,'%m-%d-%Y') }
  #=> [#<Date: 2015-03-01 ((2457083j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-03-10 ((2457092j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-03-15 ((2457097j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-03-27 ((2457109j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
d = c.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [#<Date: 2015-03-01....
```

We see that the enumerator `d` contains `d.size #=> 3` elements. The first element it will pass into the block and assign to the block variables is:

```
d1,d2 = d.next
   #=> [#<Date: 2015-03-01 ((2457083j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
   #    #<Date: 2015-03-10 ((2457092j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
d1 #=> #<Date: 2015-03-01 ((2457083j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
d2 #=> #<Date: 2015-03-10 ((2457092j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

and we compute the rational number:

```
d2-d1 #=> (9/1)
```

which (because it will always be an integer) we can convert to an integer:

```
(9/1).to_i #=> 9
```

so we obtain:

```
d.map { |d1,d2| (d2-d1).to_i }   
  #=> [9, 5, 12]
```

Why does [Date#-](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) return a rational number rather than an integer? @Stefan gives a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606410/why-does-subtraction-between-dates-return-a-rational-type).

Comment: Beat me to it. Further more OP can use `transaction_dates.map { |transaction| Date.parse(transaction.date) }.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| (b - a).to_i }`

Comment: still getting an error, I have updated the question to show how a full object in the array looks, maybe that is causing the issue

Comment: That got it Excellent, and thank you for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your dates are in format `mm-dd-YYYY` or `YYYY-mm-dd` (it's a bit ambiguous in your question) you can use the Rails helper [`String#to_date`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date) to convert to a `Date` object. (This only works for the latter.)

```
a.map { |t| t.date.to_date }.each_cons(2).map { |a, b| (b - a).to_i }
```

Either way, you probably want to refactor your code to store your dates as a proper date data type in your database.